# How can we add a column on the fly in a dynamic table in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server

My question needs little explanation so I'd like to explain this way:
I've got a table (lets call it **RootTable**), it has one million records, and not in any proper order. What I'm trying to do is to get number of rows(**@ParamCount**) from RootTable and at the same time these records must be sorted and also have an additional column(with unique data) added on the fly to maintain a key for row identification which will be used later in the program. It can take any number of parameters but my basic parameters are the two which mentioned below.
It's needed for SQL SERVER environment.

e.g.

```
RootTable    
ColumnA       ColumnB    ColumnC
ABC           city       cellnumber
ZZC           city1      cellnumber     
BCD           city2      cellnumber
BCC           city3      cellnumber
```

Passing number of rows to return **@ParamCount** and columnA startswith 
**@paramNameStartsWith**

```
<b>@paramCount:2 <br>
@ParamNameStartsWith:BC</b>
```

desired result:

```
Id(added on the fly)   ColumnA       ColumnB      ColumnC
101                    BCC          city3        cellnumber
102                    BCD          city2         cellnumber
```

Here's another point about Id column. Id must maintain its order, like in the above result it's starting from 101 because 100 is already assigned to the first row when sorted and added column on the fly, and because it starts with "ABC" so obviously it won't be in the result set.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

NOTE: My question title might not reflect my requirement, but I couldn't get any other title.

Comment: It's bit confusing. So `rootstable` is a temp table/table type variable?

Comment: @Rahul: No its a table in my db.

Comment: I would look at teh row_number functionality if I were you and if I corectly understnd what you want.

Comment: Why is ZZC in the Resultset but not BCC? And even more, why is ColumnB of ZZC "city" while it has been "city1" in your original table? And third question: you said that the table is in no specific order but with the additional column you want to keep the order. How will you keep an order which does not exist?

Comment: @martinK: Yes you are right. I edited and put right values. Thanks

Comment: which version are you using ? 
For sql 2008 and above you can use Row_number as HLGEM has mentioned. 
Otherwise i suggest you consider another workaround like adding an identity column because if your table really has milion records, that's gonna be a performance nightmare for your application

Comment: If you can use Row_Number as suggested by others you will still have to order by something. What is the order you want to have?

Comment: @MartinK: Yes, I need data in order(Asc/Desc doesn't matter) before adding the key column on the fly and then return me number of rows I want.

Comment: OK, but do you want to order ColumnA or something else? And, as others asked, do you use SQL Server 2005 or later?

Comment: @MartinK.: Yes ColumnA and MS SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first you need your on-the-fly-ID. This one is created by the `ROW_NUMBER()` function which is available from SQL Server 2005 onwards. What `ROW_NUMBER()` will do is pretty self-explaining i think. However it works only on a partition. The Partition is specified by the `OVER` clause. If you include `GROUP BY` within the `OVER` clause, you will have multiple partitions. In your case, there is only one partition which is the whole table, therefor `GROUP BY` is not necessary. However an `ORDER BY` is required so that the system knows which record should get which row number in the partition. The query you get is:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnA) ID, ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC
FROM RootTable
```

Now you have a row number for your whole table. You cannot include any condition like your `@ParamNameStartsWith` parameter here because you wanted a row number set for the whole table. The query above has to be a subquery which provides the set on which the condition can be applied. I use a CTE here, i think that is better for readability:

```
;WITH OrderedList AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnA) ID, ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC
    FROM RootTable
)
SELECT *
FROM OrderedList
WHERE ColumnA LIKE @ParamNameStartsWith+'%'
```

Please note that i added the wildcard `%` after the parameter, so that the condition is basically "starts with" @ParamNameStartsWith.

Finally,if i got you right you wanted only `@ParamCount` rows. You can use your parameter directly with the TOP keyword which is also only possible with SQL Server 2005 or later.

```
;WITH OrderedList AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnA) ID, ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC
    FROM RootTable
)
SELECT TOP (@ParamCount) *
FROM OrderedList
WHERE ColumnA LIKE @ParamNameStartsWith+'%'
```

Comment: You're genius :). Thank you very much.
It solved my 95% problem, but here's a small issue which I got after executing this query. I didn't understand why first few records were not in the correct order, as I captured the screencast here;
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-dixkFO7kvKa1hhU3RSM0VIclk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Not sure if i see that right but i think rows 4 to 14 start with a blank. If i'm right then the sorting is correct, first is blank, then "1", then "A"